# Function from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ - Higher dimensions

Tags: manifolds

If we have a function such as: $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x$, we have a one varible function, that is living in a two dimensional space, because n+n = 1+1 = 2, so, if we have the following function: $f(x,y)= (xy, xy^{2})$, it must be a two dimensional manifold, which exists in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. How is this possible to visualize?

Why is it that given $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ n+m = the dimension the manifold is in?

Comment: The function itself isn't living in a two-dimensional space. Its *graph* is.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the graph $\{(x,f(x))\}$ of $f$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \cong \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$.

As for your other question, it's possible to visualize functions $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ via [color wheels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_wheel_graphs_of_complex_functions).